# for loop nested if control flow, JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in JavaScript code, to see how exactly a loop (specifically for loop) control flow is working, lets say code for identifying longest string in a given array? with a condition loop if.

`

```
var maxLength = 0;
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > maxLength) {
      maxLength = words[i].length;
}
  }
  return maxLength;
}
findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog');`
```

Many Thanks

Comment: please add some code, you refer, to the question.

Comment: You can add `console.log` statements at the beginning of each branch so you can trace what path the program takes.

Comment: Or any diagram to understand loops control flow with all/most possibilities in a javascript code ?

Comment: e.g 
var maxLength = 0;
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > maxLength) {
      maxLength = words[i].length;
}
  }
  return maxLength;
}
findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog');

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks.....Please see the edited now. cheers

Comment: Are you intetested in how the compiled assembly code that your browsers optimizing compiler actually executes?

Comment: @JGoodgive sure why not, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take `console.log` with an output for `i`, `words[i]` and `maxLength` to have a look what is going on.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
    var maxLength = 0,
        words = str.split(' '),
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length > maxLength) {
            maxLength = words[i].length;
            console.log('change length to', maxLength);
        }
        console.log(i, words[i], maxLength);
    }
    return maxLength;
}

console.log(findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'));
```